# Was there any reason why Luke wasn't in the Aftermath series?

Tags: star-wars, luke-skywalker, star-wars-aftermath

In the *Star Wars: Aftermath* series, we see what happens to the galaxy after the events of *Return of the Jedi*.  Han, Leia, and Chewie are all featured.  However, we don't see Luke, R2-D2 and C-3P0.

Was there any particular reason that Luke wasn't included? Did Disney tell the author not to include him?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He was (evidently) told that he couldn't include Luke. He was eventually allowed to include a Han Solo story, presumably after it became clear that the Han Solo film would be a *prequel*

> **Q. Were there any restrictions on you, like, you can’t have Luke Skywalker, you can have Han Solo — which is one of the interstitial
> stories in Aftermath.**
>
> **Chuck Wendig:** *There is, yeah, there’s a Han [story.] There were definitely some restrictions. There were things that I had written
> that they were like, “we need to pull back on this for various
> reasons.” The [Lucasfilm] story group has got this massive, braided
> universe — there’s a mobile game called Uprising; obviously you have
> [the EA-DICE video game] Battlefront; you have the film, clearly; and
> then the novels and the comics. So it’s always trying to balance that
> stuff. So it’s like, **“Well, you can talk about that character here
> because this character’s there, but then we want this character to be
> exclusive to this other thing, so you can’t mention them…” But for the
> most part, I had a few clear restrictions up front, and then I was
> allowed to run with it.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Aftermath: Finding Han Solo](http://ew.com/article/2015/09/04/fstar-wars-aftermath-han-solo/)</sup></sub>

He speaks to the fan-pressure to include Han and Luke in his books (and the more irresistible pressure from the Story Group not to do so) in the interview below.

> *The thing with Aftermath, [is that] it was tricky was, and this is where the
> pressure really came in, is it came with this **rolling thunder storm**
> of expectation right because it people, everybody wanted something
> different from that book. **They wanted Han and Luke** or they wanted a
> continuation into the The Force Awakens or they wanted secrets into
> The Force Awakens and **the story I was telling was not really able
> to do those things...***

Comment: the covers were also wildly misleading but that isn't really his fault (among the many that are....)